# How to check if mentioned user's roles are higher than message author's roles?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a mute command, and I want to check if the role of the author is higher than the role of the mentioned user.

This is what I tried

```
    let mentionedrole = message.mentions.roles.first();
    let authorrole = message.author.roles

    if(mentionedrole.position > authorrole.position) {
        message.channel.send(`You don't have access to mute this user. ${message.author}`)
        return
    }
```

The error that keeps appearing is

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')

Answer (score 1):

`Message.author` doesn't have `role` property. This is because `author` refers to the user itself, but `Message.member` refers to the user as a guild member.

Also, you should use `Messsge.member.roles.highest` to get the highest position of role.

The code would be:

```js
let mentionedRole = message.mentions.roles.first();
let authorRole = message.member.roles.highest;

if (mentionedRole.position > authorRole.position) {
  message.channel.send(`You don't have access to mute this user. ${message.author}`)
  return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still errored, I used the exact code you told me to and this is the error I got

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')

Comment: @JustRedX try `console.log`ing both mentionedRole and authorRole. Or you may also insert a breakpoint right after `authorRole` declaration. Which one is undefined?